# как удалить миграции, при этом не удалять/изменять бд?

Tags: sql, django, миграция

У меня возникла проблема с сервером CI/CD, с которым я могу взаимодействовать только через Git. Изменения в базе данных также возможны только через миграции.

Я допустил серьезные ошибки, удалив несколько миграций (файлы миграций) и отправлял изменения. В результате всё сломалось, и мне не удаётся вернуться к рабочему состоянию.

Я задумываюсь о возможности удалить таблицы миграций из базы данных с помощью миграций в приложении. После этого я хочу создать новую стартовую миграцию, чтобы база данных восстановилась в нужном состоянии, а затем отправить все изменения в репозиторий. Если такой подход невозможен, подскажите, как локально удалить все миграции из базы данных через psql. Это позволит мне создать новый бэкап с рабочими таблицами миграций.

Моя цель - удалить все миграции из базы данных и приложений, чтобы затем создать их заново.